# Using ASP.NET WebApi with a 3 Tier Architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to get to grips with the use of ASP. NET WebApi recently, I’ve watched a bunch of tutorials and read quite a bit material, but not finding the information I need. This maybe a very basic question, but my idea is to host my webapi with IIS and  was aiming for a 3 tier Architecture, something like, Presentation Tier , Business Log and Data Access.

Now I create an MVC 4 project for my presentation tier. But what I am not understanding very well is do I then create another MVC 4 project with a web api template for my business logic and strip out all the controllers, views etc?

Hope I’m making sense. 
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you should host the WebAPI in a separate ASP.NET application than your MVC project is debatable. Both approaches are correct. For example if you don't want to expose the WebAPI to the public you could host it in some internal network that is accessible only by your MVC application. If you want to expose it to the public then you could host it alongside with your MVC application. So it would really depend whether you want to expose an HTTP API to the public or not.

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for the answer. Yes I would want to expose my api to the public. So my understanding is would have 2 separate projects, my my mvc project then my webapi as the service.

Comment: Not necessary. Both could be hosted in the same project in this case. But you could have them hosted in separate projects as well if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

3 tier architecture doesn't mean (in the general case) SOA (Service Oriented Architecture). If you really need SOA - it's better to have separate projects for API project (Service) and Web UI (Presentation). But if you just need SOA and you don't need REST services (for public access) then it maybe will better to use WCF instead of WebAPI.

Comment: Yeah public access would be required. So separate projects would be the way to go. Thanks Oryol.

Answer (score 0):

Marcel, your MVC is pattern in order to define your presentation tiers, you can also use WebForms, but you have selected MVC,

You must also create Business Layer and DataAccess Layer. these tiers are independent of MVC.

Select MVC just permit you to facilitate unit test (Controller) , facilitate future changing on view's technology, separate businness logic from presentation ...